# What is the maximum value for a weapon?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

I know that the game hasn't been out for more than a week, but I was wondering what the maximum value can be for a weapon. Right now I have a Pudgy Palm that has a value of 322. Any answers would help.

Comment: I have a Bullet Blade that's 323, so it's definitely higher than 322.

Comment: I have a Reaper palm that's 345, but that took awhile to make x___x;

Answer (score 2):

I've seen several weapon values in the high 340s, and one unverified report of a weapon value of 351. There seems to be a soft cap around 340, where it becomes very difficult to raise a fused weapon's value even if both parts have very high values.

If you do push through it the practical quality of the weapon is suspect. It will have a high value but you won't have a lot of options for what abilities are on it, and they probably won't complement the weapon's style well (e.g. you'll get homing bonuses on a club, six star melee on a staff). A high-value weapon without useful bonuses is a liability in PvP. You're better off fusing those abilities into something of lower value where they'll actually work.

Given the numbers I've seen, I'd *guess* that the maximum value is 355. Values seem to asymptotically approach something in that range; I've never seen a value higher than that; and since the minimum value is 100, it's exactly eight bits of range.

Comment: + for the bitwise approach.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value is 342.

Although fusions tend to move the value towards 300, it is possible to fuse up from the low 300s.

Also, the highest value weapons you can receive from Palutena via Spotpass is approximately 308.

Comment: One of the comments on this question claims otherwise (Reaper Palm 345). Do you have proof or a source that 342 is the maximum?

Comment: I actually don't have proof, I got that value from reading pretty much every available forum topic about it. Thse general consensus is that 342 is the maximum value. There are people claiming to have values over 350 or even over 700, but they appear to be either lying or mistaken about the value. No images of a weapon with a value above 342 have emerged. It is also stated on the weapon fusions guide found here: http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997768-kid-icarus-uprising/faqs/64051